# Error in na.fail.default(list(Fe = c(568L, 437L, 599L, 1016L, 670L, 1951L, : missing values in object

Tags: r

I am trying to run a PLSR model using Fe concentration with XRF spectra. The spectra matrix contains some zero values.
The code I am using upto the point where the error message pops up is as follows:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
dataset<-data.frame(cbind(chem_properties$Fe, xrf_spectra))
names(dataset)[1]<-"Fe"
summary(dataset$Fe)
dim(dataset)
plot(dataset$Fe)

#######################################
## Building calibration model

# Dataset partitioning
set.seed(100)
pls_Fe <- createDataPartition(dataset$Fe, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)
training <- dataset[pls_Fe,]
testing <- dataset[-pls_Fe,]
summary(training$Fe)
summary(testing$Fe)

# =================================================
# Model 

tc <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 5)
tg <- data.frame(ncomp = seq(2, 15, by =1))
pls_rcv <- train(Fe~., 
                 data = training,
                 preProcess = c("center", "scale"),
                 method = "pls",
                 tuneGrid = tg,
                 trControl = tc) 

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

whenever I run the last line (i.e pls_rcv) this error message shows up;

............Error in na.fail.default(list(Fe = c(568L, 437L, 599L, 1016L, 670L, 1951L,  :
missing values in object  ..............

Although my question is similar to some previously asked questions, I have tried some of the suggested solutions in those cases but none seems to be working. Maybe I am rather doing something wrong.

One of the suggestion was to use na.exclude() on the whole data frame.
I will be grateful to receive feedbacks from you.

Comment: Yeah you could do na.complete on the entire data from. The other question is to make sure that you don't have any factors that get dropped between partitions (e.g. a predictor appears in one partition but not another).

Comment: @MDEWITT, kindly elaborate what you mean by I can apply na.complete on the entire data frame. Also, how can I ensure that I don't have any factors dropped between partitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the first pass at an answer, but without peaking at a subsample of your data this is the gist I can give.

First, we can set up some fake data and add some missing cases to solve the first issue.

```
# Some fake data
dat <- mtcars

# Now lets add some missing data

dat[sample(x = 1:nrow(dat), size = 5),
    sample(x = 1:ncol(dat), size = 5)] <- NA
```

Now we we looks at our data, we see we have some missing values:
(the function counts the mising cells per column then turns the output into a dataframe for easier presentation)

```
as.data.frame(lapply(dat, function(x) sum(is.na(x))))

#>  mpg cyl disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1   0   5    0  0    5  5    0  5  5    0    0
```

If we know that we can't have missing values, we can then use the `complete.cases` function to only keep those rows that do not have any NAs.

```
dat_complete <- dat[complete.cases(dat),]
```

This removes some records (in my case 5)

```
nrow(dat) -nrow(dat_complete)
#> [1] 5
```

Aside: If dropping missing data is problematic (e.g. discarding information from these data can bias your estimates. Perhaps the data are not missing completely at random, or there was an instrument malfunction that is known), there are many methods for imputation and joint estimation of the missing values.

The second problem deals with splits not containing all of the factors.

For example, if I were to add a factor to my data set and generate the partitions, it is important to see if I capture the factor in my training data.

```
# Add factor (note D is a rare letter)
library(caret)
dat_complete$my_factor <- factor(sample(x = letters[1:4], 
                                        size = nrow(dat_complete),
                                        prob = c(.7,.2,.15,.05), replace = T))

pls_Fe <- createDataPartition(dat_complete$mpg, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)
training <- dat_complete[pls_Fe,]
testing <- dat_complete[-pls_Fe,]
```

When I look at my testing and training data I see that while my testing data has a "D", my training data do not.

```
table(training$my_factor)
#> a  b  c 
#> 14  6  0 
table(testing$my_factor)
#> a b c 
#> 5 1 1
```

A model cannot reliably predict on a new factor level (generally speaking, of course. there are more methods).

How to fix this? You can always convert the factors to numbers if that makes sense in the context (adds biase, but allows your model to work). You might need to drop your split (rather than 70% training, do 60% and see if  you capture some of the low incidence samples). If the predictors aren't relevant, then remove them from consideration. Additionally, given this is PLS, you could also try one-hot encoding. This splits a factor column into n-1 columns with a 1 or 0 representing factor representation. Do this on the full data set (only if you know that you will always observe the factors e.g. the value can only take on a category).

```
dumz <- dummyVars(~my_factor, data = dat_complete)

dat_dummies <- cbind(dat_complete, predict(dumz, dat_complete))

dat_dummies <- dat_dummies[,names(dat_dummies) !="my_factor"]

pls_Fe <- createDataPartition(dat_dummies$mpg, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)


training <- dat_dummies[pls_Fe,]
testing <- dat_dummies[-pls_Fe,]
```